# Creating a bold line in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Hello I'm creating a sudoku game in pygame and while making the board I wanted to make all lines black but some thicker than others like so:

[image: sudoku board]

Do any of you know of a way to do this?

Comment: I would recommend you show what you have already done for drawing the board, and show anything you have tried for the thicker lines and describe what isn’t working, etc

Answer (score 1):

The last argument of [pygame.draw.line](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line) is optional and specifies the thickness of the line:

> draw a straight line
>
> `line(surface, color, start_pos, end_pos, width=1) -> Rect`
>
> ...
> width (int) -- (optional) used for line thickness

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for i in range(10):
        w = 3 if i == 3 or i == 6 else 1
        pygame.draw.line(window, (0, 0, 0), (50, 50+i*30), (320, 50+i*30), w)
        pygame.draw.line(window, (0, 0, 0), (50+i*30, 50), (50+i*30, 320), w)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```